# Joining 4 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I've the following tables:

```
`course`:
`id` (PK)
`userid` (FK)
`fromtimeid` (FK) --> `timetable_time`
`tilltimeid` (FK) --> `timetable_time`

`course_timetable`:
`id` (PK)
`courseid` (FK) --> `course`
`timetable_dayid` (FK) --> `timetable_day`

`timetable_time`:
`id` (PK)
`value`

`timetable_day`:
`id` (PK)
`value`
```

I want to feed the `$userid` and want to get the array containing the timetable of that user.

The idea that I'm trying to work is:

1. Get the userid.
2. Get the courses corresponding to that `userid` and the `fromtimeid` and `tilltimeid`
3. Join the `timetable_time` table to get the values of `fromtimeid` and `tilltimeid` fetched from #2.
4. Get the days from `course_timetable` table by joining `course_timetable.courseid` with `course.id` (fetched from #3)
5. Join `timetable_day` and get the values of days.

I've tried doing the following but it throws an error:

```
SELECT `course`.*, `course_timetable`.*
FROM (`course`)
JOIN `course_timetable` ON `course_timetable`.`courseid` = `course`.`id`
JOIN `timetable_day` ON `timetable_day`.`id` = `course_timetable`.`timetable_dayid`
JOIN `timetable_time` ON `timetable_time`.`id` = `course`.`fromtimeid`
JOIN `timetable_time` ON `tiemtable_time`.`id` = `course`.`tilltimeid` 
WHERE `userid` = $id
```

The error displayed is:

```
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'timetable_time'

SELECT `course`.*, `course_timetable`.* FROM (`course`) JOIN `course_timetable` ON `course_timetable`.`courseid` = `course`.`id` JOIN `timetable_day` ON `timetable_day`.`id` = `course_timetable`.`timetable_dayid` JOIN `timetable_time` ON `timetable_time`.`id` = `course`.`fromtimeid` JOIN `timetable_time` ON `timetable_time`.`id` = `course`.`tilltimeid` WHERE `teacherid` = 0
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you also have a question to us? (EG. What is your problem?)

Comment: @nl-x: The MySQL query isn't working. :(

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? What is your output and what is your expected output ?

Comment: @nl-x: Edited the question with the error being displayed.

Comment: Give at least one of the references to `timetable_time` an alias, e.g. `JOIN timetable_time AS t1` etc.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is, where you find yourself saying "it doesn't work", delete that from the question, and replace it with what you expected, and what you actually received. For. Every. Single. Question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're joining with the same table multiple times, you need to give them aliases to disambiguate them:

```
JOIN `timetable_time` t1 ON t1.`id` = `course`.`fromtimeid`
JOIN `timetable_time` t2 ON t2.`id` = `course`.`tilltimeid`
```

Answer (score 2):

You are joining `timetable_time` twice.

First off I wonder if this is necessary. But If so, you need to give at least one of them an alias:

`JOIN SomeTimable AS SomeTableAlias ON ...`

Also when referencing that specific table you need to use the alias. So use the alias in the SELECT and the ON clauses.

(btw. you may omit the keyword `AS` when aliassing a table.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're joining the table `timetable_time` twice and use the same name. Change it to something like:

```
SELECT `course`.*, `course_timetable`.*
FROM (`course`)
JOIN `course_timetable` ON `course_timetable`.`courseid` = `course`.`id`
JOIN `timetable_day` ON `timetable_day`.`id` = `course_timetable`.`timetable_dayid`
JOIN `timetable_time` t1 ON t1.`id` = `course`.`fromtimeid`
JOIN `timetable_time` t2 ON t2.`id` = `course`.`tilltimeid` WHERE `userid` = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign alias to your timetable_time table in the join like this :

```
SELECT `course`.*, `course_timetable`.*
FROM (`course`)
JOIN `course_timetable` ON `course_timetable`.`courseid` = `course`.`id`
JOIN `timetable_day` ON `timetable_day`.`id` = `course_timetable`.`timetable_dayid`
JOIN `timetable_time` AS `tt1` ON `tt1`.`id` = `course`.`fromtimeid`
JOIN `timetable_time` AS `tt2` ON `tt2`.`id` = `course`.`tilltimeid` 
WHERE `userid` = $id
```